# Log in and change url for scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to Log in on imdb.com, first, and then go to another url on imdb, and then to scrape some data. But I can not log in, and I can not figure out why ? 
(I have real login credentials, I used example here)

```
class QuotesLoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'q'
    login_url = 'https://secure.imdb.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.c' \
                'om%2Fap-signin-handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&' \
                'openid.assoc_handle=imdb_pro_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1' \
                'kYl9wcm9fdXMiLCJyZWRpcmVjdFRvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm8uaW1kYi5jb20vIn0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.op' \
                'enid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0'
    start_urls = [login_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract the  token value
        token = response.xpath("//input[@name='appActionToken']/@value").get()
        # create a python dictionary with the form values
        data = {
            'appActionToken': token,
            'email': 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'password': 'mypassword',
        }
        # submit a POST request to it
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_quotes)


    def parse_quotes(self, response):

        open_in_browser(response)
        print(response.xpath("//span[@class='display-name']/text()").get())
```

I expect to log in and get my name, but I get None.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Selenium library? This code should get you logged in, you can then find the text via the find_element_by_xpath() method

```
    import selenium

    url = 'https://secure.imdb.com/ap/signin? 
    openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fap- 
    signin- handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_pro_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl9wcm9fdXMiLCJyZWRpcmVjdFRvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm8uaW1kYi5jb20vIn0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('location_of_driver')
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ap_email').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_id('ap_password').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit').click()
```

Comment: yes, I can finish this with selenium, but it is very slow, and I have a few thousand urls. So I am trying to find a way to finish this with scrapy. Thank you for your time.           @wafftimus.prime